# Abstract base class and hierarchy - C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, hierarchy, abstract

I have an abstract class IExecutable

```
class IExecutable
{
public:
    virtual ActionStatus Execute() = 0;
};
```

With an intermediate class Action

```
class Action : public IExecutable
{
    virtual ActionStatus Execute();
};
```

which implements Execute(), and other final classes, such as GoTo

```
class GoTo : public Action
{
    ...
};
```

GoTo does not implement Execute(). The compiler sees GoTo as an abstract class because it doesn't implement Execute().

Two questions:
Isn't the fact that Action implements Execute() enough so that GoTo shouldn't need to implement it?
And if not, how would that be fixed? It doesn't make sense to have to reimplement Execute() for every final class when it's the same for all final Actions.

Comment: This should work just fine actually, are you sure you're implementing Execute() correctly in the Intermediate?

Comment: Your example compiles in VC providing Action::Executable is defined.

Comment: This compiles for me, assuming I define virtual ActionStatus Execute(); in addition to its declaration there. (eg by changing the ";" to a "{}")

Comment: Its a little strange and a potential source of trouble, that Execute isnt declared in the public section of class Action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this isn't the whole story. `GoTo` will be abstract if there is any pure virtual function without implementation somewhere up the hierarchy.

In C++11, you can ensure that `Execute` is properly implemented using the `override` keyword:

```
virtual ActionStatus Execute() override;
```

This will cause a specific diagnostic if you accidentally declare a new virtual function instead of an override.

You can specify that `GoTo` is not the base of anything using `final`, which may cause the compiler to complain if it is abstract (but this may not be required):

```
class GoTo final : public Action
```

In any case, the compiler *should* tell you what function was not implemented to help you track down this kind of bug.

Comment: this is the error message I get

    d:\abertay\goap\goap\stab.cpp(34): error C2259: 'GOAP::Stab' : cannot instantiate abstract class
    1>          due to following members:
    1>          'GOAP::ActionStatus GOAP::IExecutable::Exectue(void)' : is abstract
    1>          d:\abertay\goap\goap\iexecutable.h(11) : see declaration of 'GOAP::IExecutable::Exectue'

Comment: @albizgil You misspelled `Execute`. The `override` tag would have caught this more specifically.

Comment: well that's embarrassing!

Comment: yet depressingly common :)